# For some reason my if statement triggers no matter what

Tags: javascript, if-statement, discord, discord.js

```
bot.on('message', async msg => {
    let args = msg.content.split(" ");
if(!msg.guild) return;
if(msg.author.bot) return;

if (msg.content === '<prefix>') {

    const req = await GuildModel.findOne({ id: msg.guild.id });
    if (!req) return msg.reply('Sorry! doc doesnt exist.');
    return msg.reply(`Found a document! Prefix: ${req.prefix} Suffix: ${req.suffix}`);

}else if(msg.content.includes(`<setprefix>`)) {
    const req = await GuildModel.findOne({ id: msg.guild.id });
    if(!req) return msg.reply('Sorry there was an error!');
    await GuildModel.findOneAndUpdate({ id: msg.guild.id }, { $set: { suffix: `${args[1]}`}}, { new: true})};
    
    return msg.channel.send('Your new prefix is asdasd')

})
```

So essentially my problem is that when I test the bot any message sent in any server the bot is  in is responded with `Your new prefix is asdasd` Ive tried to troubleshoot but Ive hit my limit and cant figure it out. Im using discord.js and have received no errors in my console! Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please add some sample input that shows the behavior.

Comment: sending anything in any channel results in the line `Your new prefix is asdasd` being sent by the bot

Answer (score 0):

If you indented your code more consistently you would immediately notice that your curly braces must be mismatched, because the `}` on the last line can not both close the elseif block and the `async msg => {` block.

The reason your code compiles is that the elseif block is ended by an extra `}` on the line `await GuildModel.findOneAndUpdate(...)};`, so `return msg.channel.send(...)` is outside the if statement, and always executed.

To avoid such errors, be mindful to always indent your code consistently (one brace per indent level). Also, try to avoid writing lines that are so long and convoluted that an extra `}` is not noticed.

Comment: Solved! Thanks so much! Im an extreamly new developer so Ill have to keep that tip about properly indenting in mind